Selenium Failing to start chromedriver in docker when on m1
I'm attempting to create a Docker container that runs a ChromeDriver utilizing Selenium. The script alone runs without issue, but I am met with an error when attempting to run the container, crashing once creating the ChromeDriver in the Python script.
My Dockerfile and configuration are as follows:
# Using python 3.10 as runtime
FROM python:3.10

# Sets working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copies the Python script and environment variables file into the container
COPY get_food.py .
COPY dbInfoDocker.env .


# Installs required packages from requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


# Install Google Chrome
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget unzip && \
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get clean

    
# Runs the script
CMD ["python", "./get_food.py"]

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # don't need a GUI
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"

I have tried doing both of the following:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

But both return an error such that:
  (disconnected: unable to connect to renderer)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

I'm running this on an m1 mac, building to amd64 and emulating it. When running it on a linux machine I do not seem to run into this error.

This is because m1 is build on arm64 architecture. Not on amd64. As far as I know Chrome does not have official builds for arm64.

I am compiling it for amd64 and running it as such
